# Is this enough to verify the submitted data is from trustable sender and unchanged?

Tags: php, security, cryptography

I want to make sure the data posted is trustable (submitted by some one who has permission to do so), and also it is intact,

Don't want to make it too complicated as well.

Data is sent as JSON, so this is what I came up with, please let me know if this is a good way (while keeping it as simple as possible).

The function:

```
function simple_sign($array, $key){
    $array['salt']   = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));
    $array['verify'] = hash_hmac('sha256', serialize($array), $key);

    return $array;
}
```

Example:

```
$data = ['test'=>'data', 'name'=>'value'];

$sign = simple_sign($data, 'Secret_key_that_only_sender_and_receiver_have');

$send = json_encode($sign); // Final Output
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in crypto stuff, but hashing a message with a secret is a good way to ensure the message has not been altered ; when receiving the json, you will have to check that the json received has the same hash as the json sent. If so, the message has not been altered.

Comment: I don’t think there’s much benefit to having that random salt in there though.

Comment: @04FS Was just thinking it will make brute forcing the secret key harder (in case the key is not good enough)

Comment: have you considered PGP encryption? That can encrypt and also sign the data.

Comment: @ADyson The data itself isn't important to encrypt, it's an e-mail address an a name actually, to create an account (posted from another website), so I just want to make sure, data is intact, and I can trust it to create the account. Is this enough for that?

Comment: Yes, that should be enough for such a purpose. You don’t want to _hide_ the data from anyone along the way, you simply want to make sure it was not tampered with - so a proper hash will do, encryption would not “add” much in that respect.

Comment: "I just want to make sure, data is intact"...well that's one job which encryption (or hashing) is very well suited for. hashing might be simpler for that purpose alone. But the extra "signing" functionality in PGP can help you to be sure that the sender is genuine. But then you may consider that whatever authentication scheme your application uses is sufficient for that. It depends on the level of seriousness of the scenario. Banks for example, will usually make you 1) authenticate to the server, 2) encrypt the connection, 3) encrypt the data, 4) digitally sign the data, so covering all bases

Comment: P.S. if this is a web-based scenario, encrypt the connection, at minimum, using HTTPs. Makes it much harder to tamper with the data in transit (and it's essential anyway, if you want an authentication system which is actually secure).

Comment: @ADyson That's an awesome detailed explanation, than you very much.

Comment: Yeah, the salt is not really needed. Maybe protection against replay attacks is. If you share a key then the key should be secure enough. If you share a *password* then you need a PBKDF function, but you'd still be less secure than sharing a secret key. HMAC is fine, but I wonder why people would stringify the input to the function (using `bin2hex`, that doesn't make any sense to me, hash functions operate on binary data / arrays...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes That was a very useful tip about `bin2hex`, thank you!

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I just checked and apparently PHP only accepts strings in its hash functions, not arrays: `Warning: hash() expects parameter 2 to be string`

Comment: What about `$salt = random_bytes(16); $array['salt'] = bin2hex(salt);` and then just use `$salt` as second parameter for `hash_hmac`? Because `random_bytes` should generate a "string". Needless conversion to hex or base 64 is really one of my pet peeves.